# Did I make a bad tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently asked [a question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/212271/102999) about who Nolan North voiced in an episode of *Rick and Morty*. I made the [nolan-north](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nolan-north) tag.

I know that author tags are frowned upon (because they are misused a ton), so is this tag any different? **Should I get rid of it?**

Comment: There is no need for actor tags, they're largely pointless.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We've never used actor tags before, so there's no precedent for this.

Also, there's really no need for actor tags. Author tags might sometimes be useful, because authors define the style and subgenre of the writing - people might be interested in looking at all questions about all stories by a particular author. But actors usually don't contribute much to the *story* - they help bring it to life, they might give it a touch of their own personal flair, but people are unlikely to want to search for a list of all questions about all films that a particular actor has starred in.

### TL;DR: let's get rid of this tag.

Comment: Let's get rid of [those](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/134528/98028) as well then. There's probably a couple more actor tags out there, but these two are the ones I know

Comment: "*people are unlikely to want to search for a list of all questions about all films that a particular actor has starred in*" - On IMDB 'Actor tags' are vastly more popular than character tags. To the point that they've toyed with removing them entirely.

Comment: @Valorum well, we're not IMDb.

Comment: @Jenayah What tags? ;-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Gonna use your "mod magic" to nuke the new one as well?

Comment: @Jenayah - Really? That's news to me

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I was going to just edit it out (as a normal user, no mod magic), but really I should wait for this meta to be "concluded" first.